# Django Templates and HTML Framesets

Tags: python, django-templates

I have a question regarding django templates and html frameset's.

I would like to create three frames on my site, a header, footer, and content page. I would like the header and footer to be persistant for each view and the content page to change to reflect content selections from the header or from within links on the content page. I have django models that will reside on the content page.

Are there any good examples of using templates and framed sites? Or even better a frameset generator that I can translate into django template pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want to use frames?  Most people make sites which have the header and footer but they are all in a single page.  You do this in django by using [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) which is an incredibly cool feature once you've got your head round it and it avoids you repeating HTML layout.

If you do really want to make frames, then make a view for each frame (or use a static file).  [Frames are just HTML](http://www.quackit.com/html/examples/frames/) and are pretty easy really.